# Computing size of the zero set for prime numbers

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $f(x,y)=y^2-(x^3-x)$. Let p be prime and consider the zero-set $Z_f(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)=\{(a,b)|\ f(a,b)=0\}$. Compute the size of each set for all primes up to 50.

How do I even begin to approach this? Is it possible to do this by hand or will I need to write some code to do this for me? I don't have a ton of coding experience and am really dreading finding an algorithm for this.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? That might give an indication of what level of machinery should be used to solve it. Also, have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Came from a professor while working on cryptography. I tried looking at some examples by hand, but quickly realized that this will be impossible trying to do it by hand.

Comment: The algorithm is clear : create an array and use 3 loops to check if $ y^2-(x^3-x) \equiv 0 \bmod p$ for each $p,x,y$